# Is Reset index will create again the searchable items value it has before

Tags: 2010, search, crawling, index-reset

In SharePoint 2010 search service application  8 content sources created for SharePoint Web Application.
and searchable items - 11,991,383

In 8 content sources there is 4 web applications has huge documents and database size 3 TB (it configured RBS)
i run full crawl every weekend and incremental every day every 30 Minutes.

Now in search service there is some issues my question is

In Search Service Application, if i reset index the searchable items will be create again to 11,991,383 this number after i run full crawl for all content sources?

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the search index completely wipes the index that currently exists. Assuming the number of crawlable items is the number you quote above, then yes, this number of items should once again end up in the index when a full crawl is complete. There may be items in the index however that have been deleted and not yet removed from the old index, or new items that have been created since the last successful crawl, therefore you may end up with a slightly different number of searchable items at the end of the crawl.